# C - Get the number left after performing n%10 operation

Tags: c, math

Suppose I have a number like `n = 1462`. When I perform `i = n%10`, the value of `i = 2`. After this operation, I want the value of `n = 146`, i.e., remove the `2` from the number. How do I do this in C? Sorry I am very new to C programming. Thanks guys!

Comment: Please indicate the purpose of i = n%10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `i=n%10` use `n=n/10`. then you will get `n=146`

```
i = n%10;
n = n/10; // Solution
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for i=n%10

Comment: @SagarJain OP needs it(`When I perform i = n%10, the value of i = 2. After this operation, I want the value of n = 146, i.e., remove the 2 from the number`). After getting `i=2` only he want to make `n=146` from `n=1462`.

Answer (score 0):

The number divided by 10 will give the required output.

i = n /10;

Comment: OP stores the remainder of the division in i. So use a different variable here

Answer (score 0):

If n is an integer, then just divide 1462 by 10. You will get the answer you want.

```
n = 1462;

n = n / 10;
```

Ans: `n = 146`

You don't need to do mod operation.

Comment: `n` should be `146` instead of `142`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the div function to seek at the same time the quotient and remainder.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 1462;
    int i;
    div_t qr;

    qr = div(n, 10);
    i = qr.rem;
    n = qr.quot;

    printf("%d, %d\n", n, i);//146, 2

    return 0;
}
```